# Passing multiple objects as parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript

What I want is to pass multiples of the same object into a function of that object
what I'm trying is to make a custom Vector Math Helper.

what I am looking for is something like

```
function dotProduct(Vector3 a, Vector3 b){
   //do calculations here
   return Vector3 a.b;
}
```

But I cant seem to find anything to help.
Any thoughts?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have type hinting, everything is dynamic.

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is a little, I'm a little unsure what your asking. (unless its the above, in which case elclanrs is right)

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of vector3 object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have classes or type hinting. You can do something like:

```
var Vector3 = function(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

var dotProduct = function(a, b) {
    // do something with a.x, a.y, a.z, b.x, b.y, b.z
    return new Vector3(...);
}
```

To create a new `Vector3`, you can use the `new` keyword:

```
//                   x  y  z
var v1 = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
var v2 = new Vector3(2, 3, 4);
var product = dotProduct(v1, v2);
```

---

You can also add the `dotProduct()` function on `Vector3` instances:

```
Vector3.prototype.dotProduct = function(b) {
    // do something with this.x, this.y, this.z, b.x, b.y, b.z
    return new Vector3(...);
}
```

in which case you could call it as:

```
var v1 = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
var v2 = new Vector3(2, 3, 4);
var product = v1.dotProduct(v2);
```

---

To make your intention clear, you can add type hinting in comments:

```
/**
 * @param Number x
 * @param Number y
 * @param Number z
 * @constructor
 */
var Vector3 = function(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

/**
 * @param Vector3 b
 * @return Vector3
 */
Vector3.prototype.dotProduct = function(b) {
    // do something with this.x, this.y, this.z, b.x, b.y, b.z
    return new Vector3(...);
}
```

Most JavaScript IDEs will know what that means and will help you by emitting warnings when you don't pass `Vector3`s as arguments.